# Spring couldn't create bean of Implemented IgniteRepository

Tags: spring-boot, ignite

I am using spring boot and Ignite Database

I have created only one Repository and I am setting data in Pojo to save using IgniteRepository

Here are the required dependency for Ignite with Spring: **Ignite Version :: 2.0.0**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-core</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-indexing</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spring-data</artifactId>
            <version>${ignite.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.195</version>
        </dependency>
```

Here I am using H2 database dependencies If I don't use it I receive another error which is completely unknown.

**IgniteConfiguration :**

```
@Configuration
@EnableIgniteRepositories(excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                TempRepository.class, GarageRepository.class, CarRepository.class,
                IncidentRepository.class, MachineRepository.class, MileageRepository.class, 
                LicenseRepository.class})
})
public class IgniteSpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
     public Ignite igniteInstance() {
      IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
      // Setting some custom name for the node.
      cfg.setIgniteInstanceName("eventInsights");
      // Enabling peer-class loading feature.
      cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
      // Defining and creating a new cache to be used by Ignite Spring Data
      // repository.
      CacheConfiguration<Long, User> userCacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration<Long, User>("UserCacheConfig");

              // Setting SQL schema for the cache.
      userCacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(Long.class, User.class);

      cfg.setCacheConfiguration(new CacheConfiguration[] {
              userCacheConfig,

      });
      return Ignition.start(cfg);
     }
}
```

**UserRepository Interface:**

```
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "UserCacheConfig")
public interface UserRepository extends IgniteRepository<User, Long>{

    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Now Main Class::

```
private static UserRepository userRepo;

     private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx;
public static void main(String[] args) {
      ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
      ctx.register(IgniteSpringConfiguration.class);
      ctx.refresh();

      userRepo= ctx.getBean(UserRepository.class);
      User user=new User();
      user.setEmail("george.paul01@xyz.com");
      user.setId(1L);
      user.setPassword("password");
      userRepo.save(user);

      User getUser=userRepo.findByEmail("george.paul01@xyz.com");

      if(getUser!=null) {
          System.out.println(getUser.getEmail());
          System.out.println(getUser.getPassword());
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("User name is not found");
      }

}
```

**User Pojo:**

```
public class User implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Long id;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String password;

    @QuerySqlField(index = true)
    private String email;

    //getters and setters method here I am skipping in my question
}
```

After running I am getting error :

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'java.lang.Class>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>     at
>   com.mphasis.springreact.services.admin.AdminController.main(AdminController.java:14)
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'java.lang.Class>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
>     ... 13 more

Answer (score 0):

[`@RepositoryConfig`](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/springdata20/repository/config/RepositoryConfig.html) does not declare @Repository or @Component. Guess it doesn't get component scanned. Try:

```
@Component
@RepositoryConfig(cacheName = "UserCacheConfig")
public interface UserRepository extends IgniteRepository<User, Long>{
    User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Comment: I Resolved it....Actually I also have some spring boot dependency in pom I removed and it worked perfectly, maybe that's the reason it was giving exception though I don't know which one but still I am not using any of the imports of those dependency –